# Why is my tkinter window freezing after pop up message and needs to be minimized to run

Tags: python, tkinter

#after the function (email_saving()) gets called the window freezes and it doesn't execute the code in the function. i need to minimize it or just make another window appear before it so it can work but like i said no code from the function is executed, i have tried to change the opening mode from "r" to "w" to "a" but nothing worked

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox, simpledialog
import random
import pyperclip
import json
import os

letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v',
           'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R',
           'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
numbers = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
symbols = ['!', '#', '$', '%', '&', '(', ')', '*', '+']

password_list = []
password = ""



def email_saving():
    with open("email save.txt", "a+") as email_saving_var:

        if os.path.getsize("email save.txt") == 0:

            answer = simpledialog.askstring("hello", "Enter your email address")
            input_email.insert(0, string=answer)
            email_saving_var.write(answer)
        else:

            answer_to_get = messagebox.askokcancel("Asking", "Would you like to use your previous E-mail")
            if answer_to_get:
                reading=email_saving_var.read()
                input_email.insert(0, string=reading)
                input_website.focus_set()

            else:
                with open("email save.txt", "w") as email_saving_var:
                    input_email.delete(0, END)
                    answer = simpledialog.askstring("hello", "Enter your email address")
                    email_saving_var.write(answer)
                    input_email.insert(0, string=answer)




# ---------------------------- Website Search --------------------------------#
def search():
    password_data = open("Passwords Wallet.json","r")
    password_json = json.load(password_data)
    print(password_json)
    if str(input_website.get()) in password_json:
        email_getting= password_json[str(input_website.get())]["Email"]
        password_getting = password_json[str(input_website.get())]["Password"]
        messagebox.showinfo("Your Info", f"your email: {email_json}\nyour password: {password_json}")
    else:
        messagebox.showerror("Error", "Password not found")
    password_data.close()


# ---------------------------- PASSWORD GENERATOR ------------------------------- #
def generate():
    password_list = []

    input_password.delete(0, END)
    for _ in range(5):
        password_list.append(random.choice(letters))
        password_list.append(random.choice(numbers))
        password_list.append(random.choice(symbols))
        random.shuffle(password_list)

    password = "".join(password_list)
    input_password.insert(0, string=password)
    pyperclip.copy(password)


# ---------------------------- SAVE PASSWORD ------------------------------- #
def saving():
    data_dict = {
        input_website.get(): {
            "Email": input_email.get(),
            "Password": input_password.get(),
        }
    }
    if input_website.get() == "":
        messagebox.showerror("Error", "website can't be empty")
        input_website.focus()
    elif input_password.get() == "":
        messagebox.showerror("Error", "Password can't be empty")
        input_password.focus()
    else:
        is_ok = messagebox.askokcancel("confirmation message", "Are you sure?")
        if is_ok:

            try:
                with open("Passwords Wallet.json", "r") as password_save:
                    data = json.load(password_save)
            except:
                with open("Passwords Wallet.json", "w") as password_save:
                    json.dump(data_dict, password_save, indent=4)
            else:
                data.update(data_dict)
                with open("Passwords Wallet.json", "w") as password_save:
                    json.dump(data, password_save, indent=4)


            finally:

                input_website.delete(0, END)
                input_password.delete(0, END)


# ---------------------------- UI SETUP ------------------------------- #
window = Tk()
# window.minsize(width=400, height=400)
window.title("PASSWORD GENERATOR")
window.config(padx=50, pady=50)

canvas = Canvas(width=200, height=200)
image = PhotoImage(file="logo.png")
canvas.create_image(100, 100, image=image)
canvas.grid(column=1, row=0)

input_email = Entry()
input_email.config(width=57)

input_website = Entry()
input_website.config(width=35)

input_password = Entry()
input_password.config(width=35)

label_website = Label(text="Website:")

website_search = Button(text="search", command=search)
website_search.config(width=10)

label_email = Label(text="Email/Username:")



label_password = Label(text="Password:")

generate_button = Button(text="GENERATE PASSWORD", command=generate)
generate_button.config(highlightthickness=0)

add_button = Button(text="ADD", command=saving)
add_button.config(width=48)

email_saving()


input_website.grid(column=1, row=1)
label_website.grid(column=0, row=1)
input_password.grid(column=1, row=3)
add_button.grid(column=1, row=4, columnspan=2)
generate_button.grid(column=2, row=3)
label_password.grid(column=0, row=3)
input_email.grid(column=1, row=2, columnspan=2)
label_email.grid(column=0, row=2)
website_search.grid(column=2, row=1)

window.mainloop()
```

I tried to get focus on one of the input fields but it didn't work

Comment: After I entered email. Then I entered stackoverflow.com and the press search... I got an error...line 53, in search
    messagebox.showinfo("Your Info", f"your email: {email_json}\nyour password: {password_json}")
                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^
NameError: name 'email_json' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

You should try creating a new thread for the function and then executing it.

For example:-

Instead of executing the function like

```
email_saving()
```

Try this:-

Firstly, import the threading module.

```
import threading
```

Then execute the function like this:-

```
thread1 = threading.Thread(target=email_saving)
thread.start()
```

Now this will prevent your window from going not responding and you can use this with any other function as well.

Comment: I will try it and get back to you

Comment: It worked but i discovered that the function isn't executing at all